# PhoneGap 1.0.0 endless prompts when html file in other folder

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm building a PhoneGap (1.0.0)/jQueryMobile(1.0b1) application on Android, but I'm running into problems when changing pages.  (Droid Incredible running 2.2)

The PhoneGap app initially opens up a file located at assets/www/account/login.html  Upon successful login, it changes window.location="dashboard.html" (dashboard.html is located in the same "account" folder.  In dashboard.html, I have a button - clicking it sets window.location="../lists/listRecords.html".

However, after the transition to the listRecords page, I get an endless series of "gap:["Device", "getDeviceInfo", "Device0", true]" prompts.  This ONLY happens when changing window.location to html files outside of the original "account" folder.  Linking to files within the "account" folder works fine.

I'd really prefer to keep my files organized in different folders... is there any way to do this without PhoneGap going crazy with infinite prompts?  (This is using a totally fresh version of PhoneGap 1.0.0 js, jar, and plugins.xml, so it's not a version mismatch issue)

Comment: getting these errors with phonegap 1.3.0 and jquery mobile 1.0.  Any ideas what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Go to the PhoneGap -> Getting Started -> Android section and make sure you follow the instructions exactly.  This solved the problem for me.  (I think I didn't have an XML file or hadn't tweaked one of the AndroidManifest.xml lines since the upgrade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd come back and answer this.  Usually when you get weird phonegap errors, the key thing is to go back to their "Getting Started" page for whichever platform you're on, follow their instructions exactly (with their updated files), and copy over your old html/js/css files.  In this case, it turned out that my XML file was improperly done for the newer version of PhoneGap

Answer (score 0):

make sure you upgrade to version 1.1  as version 1 was a very buggy release that more or less broke everything.
also you wouldn't usually create pages in folders for a phonegap app, but actually create pages on the fly as and when you need them in order to keep cache and memory down as low as possible and to try and keep as much native feel as possible.

Answer (score 0):

On android versions greater than 1.2.0, it could be a whitelisting issue: [What is the state of whitelisting in phonegap 1.3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899608/what-is-the-state-of-whitelisting-in-phonegap-1-3-0)