# loading url into a div using jQuery in an app wrapped by phonegap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to develop a proof of concept where I use jQuery to load HTML content into a div.  I'm using jQuery, jQueryMobile, and PhoneGap.  I have a simple index.html with a single jQueryMobile page.  I want to inject into the content div the results (HTML) of a call to my server.  I'm testing this on an Android emulator.  Here's my code:

```
function onBodyLoad()
{    
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false); 
}

function onDeviceReady()
{     
    var url = "http://www.myserver.com/content/qwerty";
    $("#applicationContainer").load(url);
}
<body onload = "onBodyLoad();">

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Content</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="applicationContainer" data-role="content"> 
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

This is not working.  What am I doing wrong?  I can load my android apk file into the emulator and open up the app, but I can't load HTML into the content div.  My concept is to create android and iphone mobile apps using phonegap to load html content into pages.  What am I missing?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to white-list an external server:

[What is the state of whitelisting in phonegap 1.3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899608/what-is-the-state-of-whitelisting-in-phonegap-1-3-0)

Look for phonegap.xml (mine is in res folder - ~/res/xml/phonegap.xml) and add:

This allows all domains.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your index.html must also be on the same server. It's Same-Origin-Policy.

Think about it: If you could load every page into your site, you could do something like this:

`$("#container").load("http://facebook.com/messages"`). Every website could read your private messages. This is the reason why you can only access sites from the same domain.

There are some workarounds, for example Yahoo Pipes.

Comment: Not true for PhoneGap applications.

Comment: It's my understanding that same origin policy is not applicable for mobile phonegap apps

Comment: it's true that the same origin policy is not applicable if you're using phonegap. becausae it uses the "file://" protocol to load the html files not http.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this tutorial that might explain the reason I can't load content from an external server:

http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/

Towards the end of the tutorial, the author says PhoneGap 1.x+ added "ExternalHosts" to project plist file (their example deals with iOS).  With this change you must whitelist servers that you access from within your app, so make sure to add any domains.  So, how do you whitelist an external server for an Android PhoneGap implementation?  Do you think this explains why I can't load content in my simple example?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your domain "www.myserver.com" to the whitelist file?

Nevermind, I guess that's for iOS only.

Can you put an alert in your onDeviceReady to make sure that code is getting called?

Comment: i added an alert to show the url value and i did receive the alert

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#page").bind("pageshow",function(){
 //your jquery operation when pageshow event triggered.

 var url = "http://www.myserver.com/content/qwerty";
 $("#applicationContainer").load(url);

});

function onBodyLoad()
{    
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false); 
}

function onDeviceReady()
{     
   //your phonegap operation.

}
</script>
<body onload = "onBodyLoad();">

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Content</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="applicationContainer" data-role="content"> 
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for code snippet.  I can get your version to work in a browser, but when I build this simple code into an Android apk file using Dreamweaver and load it in the Android emulator, it doesn't work.  I put alerts in the "pageshow" method and the alert fires in the emulator, but the call to my server to get HTML doesn't fire.  There is no activity according to Fiddler.  Is there soemthing I need to do with android emulator?

Comment: perhaps you might wanna try using the .ajax instead of using .load