# Are 'POST' cross domains ajax requests allowed in PhoneGap / jQuery Mobile apps?

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova, webview

As in the title: Are '**POST**' cross domains ajax requests allowed in PhoneGap / jQuery Mobile apps in webview mode? Providing that both `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages` and `$.support.cors` are set to true.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need either of those.

if you're in iOS just add a new external host and set it's value to *

if you're in Android add this to your manifest

```
<access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" />
```

here's another post about the same topic - 
[What is the state of whitelisting in phonegap 1.3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899608/what-is-the-state-of-whitelisting-in-phonegap-1-3-0)

Comment: do you know what to if it is just for an jQuery Mobile app ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales this works across the board. if you do a catch all whitelist which is * then you're set and good to go. Since apps are in a sandbox crossdomain is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

try this also