# phonegap load variable url

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using phonegap. I need to load external website depending on the input. The input data are passed as an Object from previous page.Then combined to generate the url. URL will be stored in variable $link. And then use `load()` to get the website. However it seems not work for putting url variable in `load()`. How can I solve it?

```
$(document).on( "pagebeforeshow", "#page1", function( e ) {
            var word2 = passDataObject1;
            var method2 = passDataObject2;
            var location2 = passDataObject3;
            switch(location2)
            {
            case "Entire_Collection":
                location2="%29+";
            break;
            case "Reference_Collection":
                location2="%29+c%3A4";
            break;
            }

            var $link = 'http://....'+method2+word2+location2+'.....';
            $('#result1').load($link);
        });
```

Comment: What does chrome/firebug console say? I suspect you cannot even do $('#result1').append('hello'). If so, then it has nothing to do with load() - i.e. your JQM page is not even rendered correctly for DOM manipulation. Just a wild guess.

Comment: I can load the website if I don't use variable $link. It can give what I want if I type `$('#result1').load('http://........');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring the variable as `var link = 'http://....'+method2+word2+location2+'.....';`
without the `$`.

Comment: For all the international english speakers! :)

Answer (score 0):

check by adding your domain "www.yourdomain.com" to the whitelist file!!!

Found @ [How to white-list an external server: Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899608/what-is-the-state-of-whitelisting-in-phonegap-1-3-0)

This allows all domains, hope this ll help.